# Suexec PHP does not load php.ini

Tags: centos, php, apache-2.4, suexec

I'm using FastCGI with suEXEC for PHP on CentOS 7. My wrapper script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
PHPRC=/home/ben/etc/
export PHPRC
export TMPDIR=/home/ben/tmp/
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi -c /home/ben/etc/php.ini
```

The PHPRC variable is set and phpinfo shows it but the custom php.ini will not be used. Phpinfo just says:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In my fast-cgi wrappers it is configured like:

```
#!/bin/bash
PHPRC=$PWD/../etc/php7.2
export PHPRC
umask 022
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=99999
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
SCRIPT_FILENAME=$PATH_TRANSLATED
export SCRIPT_FILENAME
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

So your `PHPRC` should do the trick. No need for the `-c /home/.../php.ini` parameter.

Is `/home/ben/etc/php.ini` file readable for the fast-cgi user (probably *ben*)?